# Could not find ildasm.exe at location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft visual studio 11.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sdk

How does the *Developer command prompt for  Visual studio 2012* search the location of ildasm.exe. Running command window  *Developer command prompt for  Visual studio 2012*  will point to location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft visual studio 11.0` but at this location ildasm.exe couldn't be found. In fact input to command window, ildasm.exe will open the ildasm tool.

Can any one clarify how does `Developer command prompt for  Visual studio 2012` locate the physical ildasm.exe.

Answer (score 38):

When you start `Developer command prompt for  Visual studio 2012` the command (it is a bat script) modifies environment `PATH` (and other things that does not matter in this case).

You can see the difference when you type `set` in `Developer command prompt for  Visual studio 2012` and in classic `cmd`.

When you open `Developer command prompt for  Visual studio 2012` it is true that you land in 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft visual studio 11.0` but thanks to the modified `PATH` variable windows will look in every directory mentioned by this variable.

It will find `ildasm.exe` in i.e. `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\`.

Comment: Thank you, as said the physical path is added to PATH variable, in that case if i open a new cmd window follows the previous action i should also be able to run Ildasm command correct? but i couldnt-- can i know whats the reason.

Comment: I did this. Run cmd. Then in cmd I typed `set "PATH=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\;%PATH%"`. I did not close this cmd because the NEW Path is available in this window. I typed `ildasm` and a window showed. Does it behave differently when you do it?

Comment: Don't set your path using command 'set' as told when we open 'Developer command prompt for visual studio 2012' its sets the path. Now run your cmd then type ildasm it wont work.

Comment: Win7 64, VS2013 Premium: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools

Comment: for vs2015 windows 10 64bit with .net framework 4.6.1, location was C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools

Answer (score 24):

Please check following section. I am using VS 2013 & 2015.

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.1 Tools

If you want to use them from Visual Studio directly, you can try following URL:

[Launch ildasm tool from inside visual studio itself how](http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/01/05/did-you-know-you-can-launch-ildasm-tool-from-inside-visual-studio-itself-how/)

Comment: The link on your answer is dead

Comment: Here are some instructions for how to launch Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022 from the start menu. Once the command prompt launches, type "ildasm": [Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 1):

There are various developer command prompts for different targets, each starts a batch file that modifies the `PATH` and some other things so that various developer programs can work.

Note that each command window started by these batch files starts with the `PATH` specified via the user and system environment settings. The batch files then modify the `PATH` etc within just that command window. Starting a new command window will not get the settings from the batch file as it does not modify the user and system environment settings.

If you really want easy access to `ildasm.exe` frequently from a command window you can modify the user environment settings. On Windows 7 you can access these settings via the properties of the computer where you select "advanced system settings" and then "environment variables".

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2022, you can launch the ILDASM GUI through the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.

Go to your start menu and start typing "Developer Command Prompt..." and it should come up.

Once the developer command prompt for Visual Studio has launched, type in ILDASM to bring up the GUI. You can use the File menu to locate the files that you want to analyze.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the below path in Windows 10  machine.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools