# Should cl (windows visual studio compiler) work from any command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, compiler-errors

I installed visual studio 2012 on my D drive since my C is full and was wondering if cl command should work from any command line or does it specifically have to be from the visual studio command line tool? I am wondering this because I am trying to build the boost library and in the bootstrap.bat file to do all the building for me is currently giving me an error saying the cl command isn't recognized.Clearly its not finding the cl.exe file in visual studios bin. I know adding an environmental variable ("PATH" variable) will fix my issue but should there already be a PATH variable?

Comment: Yeah i was doing more research and figured that out. So should i run the bootstrap.bat to build boost from inside the visual studio cmnd prompt?
where did ur comment go? Now i look like i'm talking to myself haha.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006728/could-not-find-ildasm-exe-where-developer-command-prompt-for-visual-studio-2012/23011756#23011756

Answer (score 1):

There's always a PATH environment variable.  It however isn't preset to include the Visual Studio bin directories.  After all, you are normally running the compiler from the IDE, it takes care of setting up the environment correctly.  It is not the only variable that matters, the INCLUDE and LIB variables are very important as well.  Respectively to find .h and .lib files.

Programs on Windows in general avoid depending on the environment, it is very brittle since it is in effect a massive machine-wide global variable that any installer can screw up.  They often do.  True for most programs, not for the C++ tool chain since it still relies on the way it was done in the 1970s.  Nothing much has changed since then as far as building C and C++ programs go.

So, sure, you can run CL.EXE from any command prompt, you'll just spend a lot of time setting the environment correctly.  The provided Visual Studio Command Prompt shortcut just makes it fast, easy and avoids mistakes.

The Boost [getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) web page is a bit of a tragedy.  But follow the recommendations, its says to use the Visual Studio Command Prompt if you want to build from the command line so of course that's what you ought to do.  How to build from the IDE is also described, just more ways to keep you out of trouble.

Comment: Yea that's all great info. I meant an env variable just for the location of cl.exe lib.exe ect... so that when i run that batch file that builds/sets up bjam.exe(which does the actual build) i don't get errors like cl is not a command. But if i run the batch file from the visual studios command line it should know all those commands correct? Thanks for the help and info its much appreciated.

Comment: No idea what "the batch file" might mean.

Comment: its the boost library's windows batch file that is a set of commands that installs bjam.exe which you use to build the boost library. I got it sorted out. You can call bootstrap.bat (which has the cl.exe call inside of it that wouldn't work earlier) when inside the visual studios command prompt and it works. "the batch file" was in my question sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help